# Is it possible to begin a subsequent question with "Or" without repeating the subject?

Tags: sentence, subjects

Examples:

Are you planning a trip with your friends? Or collaborating on a project with your peers?

Have you discovered a new movie you'd love to watch? Or found an original recipe you'd like to try out?

Comment: Is this spoken, or written? And why can't sentences begin with conjunctions?

Comment: 'Or collaborating on a project with your peers?' is not a sentence, but a sentence fragment. It arises from punctuating more heavily 'Are you planning a trip with your friends, or collaborating on a project with your peers?' in order to give the two questions a more reasonable amount of gravitas. It is fine to use fragments as in this example, provided the format is not ultra-formal. In speech, this works very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Or' is commonly used in this way. As long as the first alternative is present before the sentence that begins with 'Or...' then you're ok.

Comment: Fair. Changed answer